# Django Webhook creates double database entries

Tags: django, django-models, dialogflow-es

I'm currently using Django to code a webhook application for google Dialogflow.
It was working fine, I was basically done.
For some reason, I now started encountering various randomly appearing problems, one of the worst being the following:
Whenever the webhook executes the user account creation call, it creates a double-database entry, which crashes the program (because my .get suddenly returns multiple elements instead of a single user).

I'm using the following simple models:

```
# model to create user entries
class TestUser(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    userID = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    registrationDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


# model to add watched movies to user
class Movie(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(TestUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    genreID = models.IntegerField (blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def list_genre_id(self):
        return self.genreID
```

The part that gets executed in my webhook while the problem occurs should be the following:

```
    if action == "account_creation":
        selection = req.get("queryResult").get("parameters").get("account_selection")
        if selection == "True":
            q = TestUser(name=f"{username}", userID=idgen())
            q.save()
            userID = TestUser.objects.get(name=f"{username}").userID
            fullfillmenttext = {"fulfillment_text": "Alright, I created a new account for you! Would you like to add "
                                                    "some of your favorite movies to your account?",
                                "outputContexts": [
                                    {
                                        "name": f"projects/nextflix-d48b9/agent/sessions/{userID}/contexts/create_add_movies",
                                        "lifespanCount": 1,
                                        "parameters": {
                                            "data": "{}"
                                        }
                                    }]}
```

This is the simple idgen function I'm using:

```
def idgen():
    y = ''.join(
        random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(12))
    return y
```

I'm trying to create this userID as a way of having a unique session ID in the webhook calls for all users. Something seems to mess it up, but I don't have the slightest clue what.
Thank you so much for looking over this!

Comment: Unrelated, but what's the point of `name=f"{username}"`? Why not just `name=username"`? And why save the object then get it again, rather than just using the one you already have?

Comment: I'm entirely self-taught in Django, I thought I have to do this in oder to pass it properly as a string. Probably dumb, thanks for pointing it out. I'll fix it.

Comment: I'm saving the object to add the new user-account to the database. I want to assign every user a unique ID which I can use as session ID going forward. So I'm getting the ID that was saved to the database. It was working fine for the longest of time, the only thing that crashes it now is the double-entry.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I was able to fix the issue:
The problem was apparently that I had the lifespan of a previous outputContext set to 2 instead of 1, which resulted in the answer executing the codecell twice for some reason. Man, dialogflow is such a terrible program.